# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment. error in python program

Tags: python

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import sys

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty("rate", 150)
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source, None, 10)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'alexa' in command:
                command = command.replace('alexa', '')
                print(command)
    except:
       pass
    return command
    
def run_alexa():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)

    if 'play' in command:
        video = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing' + video)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(video)

    elif 'search for' in command:
        search = command.replace('search for', '')
        talk('searching' + search)
        pywhatkit.search(search)

    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is' + time)

    elif 'who is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 3)
        print(info)
        talk(info)

    elif 'what is my name' in command:
        talk('your name is yuva dharshan')

    elif 'who are you' in command:
        talk('i am alexa, your personal voice assistant, you created me to obey\
             your orders and execute your orders sir')

    elif 'hai' in command:
        talk('hi sir how can i help you')

    elif 'open youtube' in command:
        talk('opening youtube')
        webbrowser.open("http://youtube.com", new=1)

    elif "open gmail" in command:
        talk('opening gmail')
        webbrowser.open("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm&ogbl#inbox", new=1)

    elif 'open facebook' in command:
        talk('opening facebook')
        webbrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/", new=1)

    elif 'open instagram' in command:
        talk('opening insta gram')
        webbrowser.open("https://www.instagram.com/", new=1)


    elif 'open downloads folder' in command:
        talk('opening downloads folder')
        path = "C:/Users/yuvad/Downloads"
        webbrowser.open(path)

    elif 'open control panel' in command:
        talk('opening control panel')
        os.system('control.exe')

    elif ('bye') or ('quit') in command:
        sys.exit()

    else:
        talk("pls say the command again")

while True:
       run_alexa()
```

**when I run the program I get this error:**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yuvad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\alexavoiceassistant.py", line 116, in <module>
    run_alexa()
  File "C:\Users\yuvad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\alexavoiceassistant.py", line 38, in run_alexa
    command = take_command()
  File "C:\Users\yuvad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\alexavoiceassistant.py", line 34, in take_command
    return command
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `except: pass`, ok, so what if `command = listener.recognize_google(voice)` never runs because an error was thrown in the try-block before that? Also, you should pretty much enver use a bare except clause like that

Answer (score 0):

What happens if your first try/except block catches an exception?

```py
 try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source, None, 10)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            
    except:
       pass
    return command
```

`command` has not been assigned!  But you still try to return it, hence the error.

either something like:

```py
errored = 0
MAXERR = 3
while not command and errored < MAXERR:
    try:
        ...
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
    except Exception: # preferably catch a *special type of exception*
        MAXERR += 1
if not command:
    raise Exception("Failed to get command")

return command
```

or return e.g. `None` to indicate failure:

```py
command = None
try:
    command = ...
except Exception:
    pass
return command
```

And then test for `None` in your main code.

You don't want a bare `except:` because it catches *everything*, including the system trying to terminate the process and the user pressing `Ctrl-C`.  At the very least catch `Exception`, which won't catch those two cases.